# Check identity of remote-user after password-less ssh-login?

Tags: linux, authentication, ssh, authorized-keys

After password-less ssh-login, is there any way in Linux to retrieve the identity of the remote-user that logged in?

I would like to take some different actions in the login-scripts, 
depending on from which remote host/userid I do ssh-login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The originating system's username is not recorded unless you use [something like this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f) - i.e. push the username as part of the connection. The remote host is encoded in the `SSH_CLIENT` environment variable, so that can be determined.

You could try to `finger` the remote system, but that requires `fingerd` to be running, which is not a common service these days.

You'll have better luck using specific keys for users, which can have options set at the start of the key such as `environment="NAME=value"` in the `authorized_keys` file to kind-of determine the remote user that connected. e.g.

```
environment="REMOTEUSER=fred" ssh-rsa <blahblahkey> <comment>
```

The use of the `environment` option in the key will only work if you've got `PermitUserEnvironment` set in the sshd config, otherwise the line in the `authorized_keys` gets ignored and you'll be prompted for a password.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I tried your tips. 
The SSH_CLIENT variable is set, but unfortunately useless, since we tunnel in through a common proxy. 
Finger also not possible because of firewall blocks. 
The environment="NAME=value" --seems like the sysadmins do not allow that on our servers... from what I read, it's disabled by default? When I try that, the password-less logon ceases, and I get prompted for a password, so looks like the server doesnt like that.

Comment: Yeah, if `PermitUserEnvironment` isn't set on the server the key is ignored (rejected like it's invalid). The only other silly option is to use 'command="env REMOTE=user /bin/bash', but that's just a loopy option as it will prevent non-interactive scripts. It sounds like you've got a difficult nut to crack, as the proxy hides originating IP addresses, and ssh, by default, doesn't ask for the remote username.

Comment: As a workaround, seems like something like this could work, in principle:  ssh user@server '/bin/bash --rcfile .customrc -l -i' ; It will then execute a different file than .bashrc at logon where I can do custom-setup. But its not perfect... at logon I get annoying msg "bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument; bash: no job control in this shell". Also, when I type ctrl-C in bash, it terminates the whole bash-session, and exits back to the client (i am running ssh from windows/cygwin). Any idea how to fix those issues?

Comment: you use the '-t' option to ssh, which forces it to allocate a tty to what it considers 'non-interactive' logins.

Comment: Great! Seems that solved both issues :) Mucho gracias, Pete! :)

Comment: Just a correction to my comment above. The -l flag should not be there, it then seems to ignore the --rcfile option. So the right solution is: ssh -t user@server '/bin/bash --rcfile .customrc -i'

Comment: You can also use ssh -t user@server 'env SRCHOST="'$(uname -n)'" SRCUSER="'$(id -nu)'" /bin/bash -i' and export the variables that way, but this was mentioned in the superuser.com answer